# Python Command to render vray

Tags: python, render, maya, mel, pymel

Making a small script to write out .vrscenes for me, however I'm a little stick with getting them to render.

I'm using the pymel render command, which seems to call the maya software renderer rather than vray itself ignoring all the rendersettings I have set. Anyone know if there is an alternative command?

Thanks, sorry if this has been asked before!

script as follows;

```
frames = 100
split = 1
location = "/Users/adamcheshire/Desktop/testing/testScene"

# Create a list of render frames evenly split

framesToRender =  frames/split
listToRender = []
start = 1
end = framesToRender

for i in range(0, split):
    listToRender.append([start, end])
    start += framesToRender
    end += framesToRender

# Make sure final element == to frames

listToRender[-1] = [listToRender[-1][0], frames]


# init vrscene mode

vray = pm.ls('vraySettings')[0]
DRG = pm.ls('defaultRenderGlobals')[0]

vray.vrscene_render_on.set(0)
vray.vrscene_on.set(1)
DRG.animation.set(1)
vray.animBatchOnly.set(0)

# Set and Render

for i in range(0, len(listToRender)):
    DRG.startFrame.set(listToRender[i][0])
    DRG.endFrame.set(listToRender[i][1])
    vray.vrscene_filename.set(location+"_s"+str(listToRender[i][0])+"_e"+str(listToRender[i][1])+".vrscene")
    pm.render()
    #pm.batchRender()
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: py file can be found here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19020314/vrsceneMaker.py

Basically creating a vrscene for large maya scenes can take some time, so I wanted to make a script that will cut the scene up into sections (in terms of frames to render), and write them out one after the other. So far everything works bar the render command as stated before, if I click the render button manually however it will create the vrscene as expected. 

I'm also expecting problems of delaying the next vrscene in the loop untill the preceding one has finished rendering. It's WIP so sorry if its bad

Comment: Should add that you need to import pymel.core as pm - automatically does it on mine so I forgot

Comment: You should [edit] that information and code into the question. The Dropbox content won't be around forever

Comment: Code now in many body as requested! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

i think it's something like:

```
pm.vrend()
```